# Rails 4 - Getting most sold objects with a relationship in between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `Product` model with `:name` and `price`. I also have a `Order` model with `:amount` (of units sold) and `belongs_to :product`

How could I get a array of the top 5 most sold object, in terms on units sold?

I was thinking of getting something like:

```
{"Razors"=>4, "Axes"=>2, "Cars"=>1, ...}
```

P.S.: If possible, how would it be getting the top 5 most sold objects, in terms of income made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull all needed data with one single SQL query.

You didn't mention database you are using, but here are some examples:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT products.*, SUM(amount) total_amount FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products on orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY total_amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

**PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT products.*, SUM(amount) total_amount FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products on orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id, products.name ORDER BY total_amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

Conctruct the query using Rails or use `find_by_sql` method to insert raw SQL.

Comment: While I was hoping for a Rails way of doing it, this works absolutely perfect. Thanks!

Comment: SQL query is faster in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ***very*** long winded solution but answers your original question I think.

```
#Get only products that have a price and name. (may not be required).
products = Product.includes(:orders).where.not(name: nil, price: nil)

#Sets up an empty hash
hash = {}

products.each do |product|
  product.orders.each do |order|
     hash[product.name] = [order.amount]
  end
end
```

Then you can sort your hash based on the values to sort by the amount of units sold (and also limit to 5)

```
Hash[hash.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse].take(5)
```

Interested to what others suggest via an ActiveRecord or SQL query though.